# DES ECB in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cryptography, des

I am implementing interaction with bank system. I need to use DES schipher in ECB mode.

My key is "12345678" and message is `[0xF2, 0xF3, 0x2D, 0x1A, 0xC0, 0xFD, 0x23, 0xB4]` hexadecimaly. I need to convert key to hexadecimal array and then perform sha encryption in ecb mode. Result should be `[0x3E, 0x90, 0x5F, 0xB7, 0xC5, 0xA3, 0x02, 0xB1]`

I am using

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("des-ecb")
```

, is it right? What is the best way to get pleased result.

I tried many ways and am lost. Thank you for saving me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way, how to do the encoding was:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("des-ecb")
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
output = cipher.update hash
```

Previously, I have used output from `cipher.final`